# Share CoreData code with iOS and Mac OS X

Tags: ios, macos, core-data, core-data-migration

I am in the process of writing an app for the iPad. I want to use CoreData API to do my backend. If this project is successful, I'd want to write a Mac OS X version of the app as well.

If I use CoreData for my backend, will I be able to easily share the backend classes across both the iOS platform as well as the osx platform?

All I want to do is to share the same backend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is doable. You do however want to make sure you build to the iOS platform ***then*** MacOS because MacOS includes all the Core Data capabilities of iOS but iOS lacks some found in MacOS.

Of course, make sure to keep everything as generic as possible, e.g. don't use `UIImage` or `NSImage` because they are not supported on both platforms.

Comment: Thank you. That's reassuring. I have started from the iOS end, so that shouldn't be a problem. Only going to store paths for images and other filetypes. Going to keep it to the basic datatypes.